# VBA: How to translate this cmd command to VBA Shell Code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the below Command-line in VBA Code, the command is to get all .pdf and .docx files recursively and runs just fine in CMD

```sh
dir /s *.pdf *.docx
```

Now In VBA, have the below, which is printing out ALL files recursively and not the specified extensions

```vb
Sub Run()
    Debug.Print ShellRun("cmd.exe /c dir c:\ /s *.pdf *.docx")
End Sub

Public Function ShellRun(sCmd As String) As String
    Dim oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim oExec As Object
    Dim oOutput As Object
    Set oExec = oShell.Exec(sCmd)

    ShellRun = oExec.StdOut.ReadAll
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Debug.Print ShellRun("cmd.exe /c dir /s c:\*.pdf c:\*.docx")
```

**Edit:** Following comment

You need to run `dir /s PATH\*.pdf PATH\*.docx` no space between `\*`. Also `PATH` should be repeated for both pdf and docx. However, in your code you had spaces and you also had the positions of `c:\` and the flag `/s` swapped.

Comment: Thanks it's working fine now! Mind explaining to me how does this work briefly so i understand it better?